# jwplayer - hide part of the movie with black div

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

i have a movie with built in subtitles. i want an option to hide the captions so i created a black div with absolute position to hide the captions.
The problem i'm having is when the movie is shown on full screen i can't see the black div.
i added z-index of 10000000 to this div and it works but now it also covers the jwplayer controls.

any idea how can i achieve that?

```
<div id="movie_container" class="movie_container">
   <div class="videoplayer" id="videoplayer"></div>
   <div id="hide_captions_box" class="hide_captions_box">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using jwplayer ?

Comment: yes i'm using jwplayer. i don't want to add a link because it's for my work